# Parsing JSON Swift 3 with error Code=3840

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have this error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Here is my swift code.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://example.org/file.php")! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        old_data, response, error in

        //Error Checking
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        //Response string built up
        let responseString = NSString(data: old_data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Manipulating the JSON data
        var names = [String]()

        do {
            if let new_data = old_data, 
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: new_data) as? [String: Any],
                let buildings = json["buildings"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for building in buildings {
                    if let name = building["BuildingName"] as? String {
                        names.append(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        print("Names: \(names)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

The error is happening in my 'do' statement where 'let buildings = json["buildings"]'

And below is what I get when I print the response string.

```
responseString = Optional({"buildings":[{"BuildingID":"2","BuildingName":"School of Informatics and Comp","Info":"School of higher learning.","Latitude":"39.172085","Longitude":"-86.522908"}]}Successfully Retrieved. SELECT * FROM Buildings;)
```

Any questions or advice is appreciated

Comment: Your `JSON` response is not proper, check your api where you are creating this response and remove this `Successfully Retrieved. SELECT * FROM Buildings;` This is the reason you are not getting serialized json.

Comment: Thank you @NiravD that worked for me

Comment: Welcome mate :)